# how to retrieve the json returned in a string variable in mvc4 vb.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

how can I get the json being returned from mvc4 web platform

below is my function:

```
 Public Function insertReg()
    dim res as new resObj()
    res.id=1
    res.name="test"
    return res
 End Function 

 public class resObj
     Public Property id As Integer
     Public Property name As String
 End Class
```

when I return the `res` object my mvc4 solution converts it directly to json, but I need to retrieve this json and put it in a variable for another use.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the following Namespace, you will probably need to add the relevant assembly. And then you can serialize into a JSON string

```
import System.Web.Script.Serialization;


Public Function insertReg()
    dim res as new resObj()
    res.id=1
    res.name="test"
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(res);
    return res
 End Function
```

If you want the root object to go along with the JSON than create a dynamic wrapper class.

```
       TestModel model = new TestModel();
        model.pass = "PassMe";
        dynamic Wrapper = new
        {

            TestModel = model

        };
        var JSON = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Wrapper);
```

JSON will = `{"TestModel":{"pass":"PassMe"}}`

Comment: Here you are generating the json and returning the resObj, but in my case I need to retreive the json in order to encrypt the data and send it.

Comment: You want the root model attached the JSON as well? See my edit, the json variable with hold the JSON string, add what ever logic you need to for your scenario

Comment: I got your point CSharper, but I don't want to serialize the Object. Is there any method without serializing it ?

Comment: Your question is getting the JSON notation from an object is it not?